# Java: How to set a value from javascript to a wicket component textfield

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I am using javascript to get a value from client-side using a button that is not binded to a wicket component (i.e., it doesn't have a wicket-id). Now, I need to set that value to a textfield (textarea) - that is a wicket-component, but unable to do that. If I set value in a simple textarea (not a wicket component) then it works fine. But I need that value in the wicket component so that I can get its value when the form submits.

Javascript isn't working on the wicket component.

Javascript method:

```
var text2 = document.getElementById("e2");
var text1 = document.getElementById("e1");
text1.value = "hello";
text2.value = "hello";
```

html:

```
<wicket:panel>
<form wicket:id="form" id="form" onsubmit="submit(event,this);">
<div wicket:id="myPanel">

   <input type="button" value="Verify" name="B3" onclick=GetTemplate() />

   <p><textarea name="S2" id="e2"></textarea></p>

   <p><textarea wicket:id="e1" name="S1" id="e1" ></textarea></p>

   <input type="submit" class="submitForm" wicket:id="submit" wicket:message="value:Submit" name="submit" />

</div>
</form>
</wicket:panel>
```

Java:

```
public class MyPanel  extends Panel {
 public MyPanel(...){
   ...
   Form<?> form = new Form("form", new Model());
   container = new WebMarkupContainer("myPanel");

   textArea = new TextArea<String>("e1", new Model());
   textArea.setEnabled(true).setOutputMarkupId(true).
   textArea.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
   textArea.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
   textArea.add(new ErrorIndicator());

   submitButton = (Button) new Button("submit") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
                message = textArea.getModelObject();
            }
        }.setEnabled(true);
   container.add(textArea);
   container.add(submitButton);
   form.add(container);
   add(form);
 }
```

Here, I can set value in the textarea id=e2 but not on id=e1.

Comment: "My code doesn't work" is very vague. What's the error?

Comment: I don't get any error. The value doesn't set on the textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem come from this line:

```
 textArea.setEnabled(true).setOutputMarkupId(true)
```

This will generate a custom id for the TEXTAREA (for Wicket Ajax). So, the `id` is changed and your javascript won't work anymore, because that uses the 'e1' id that is replaced.

You can add a custom data-attribute and get the component by that attribute.

For example:

```
 <p><textarea wicket:id="e1" name="S1" data-id="e1" ></textarea></p>
```

And then (for example, using jquery, something like this)

```
  $("TEXTAREA[data-id='e1']").val("hello");
```

Or, if you don't need ajax, skip calling the `setOutputMarkupId`

Comment: Wicket will not generate dynamic id if there is an `id` attribute in the markup. I don't see how this answer fixed the problem.

Comment: Ah, I did't know. Thanks for clarification. From the javadoc: "This is either the id attribute set explicitly via a call to setMarkupId(String), id attribute defined in the markup, or an automatically generated id - in that order."

Comment: @martin-g do you know what causes this behaviour here?

Comment: The id wasn't always read from markup - maybe an old Wicket version? https://github.com/apache/wicket/commit/02b7de50eff276fac2d8444d73ae2f091a580481